# configure of filebeat to elasticsearch

Tags: elk

Can't open config/certs/http_ca.crt for reading, No such file or directory
139762353411904:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('config/certs/http_ca.crt','r')
139762353411904:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load certificate
getting this issue does anybody help me to figure out this problem

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/configuring-stack-security.html#_connect_clients_to_elasticsearch_5 ..... following this documentation for connecting of Elasticsearch to filebeat

$ sudo openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -in config/certs/http_ca.crt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fingerprint you can also use the CA certificate (2nd option in the document) to establish SSL between Filebeat and Elasticsearch.
Try the below settings in your filebeat.yml for ES connection. Note: In case you want to disbale SSL, you can add the line "ssl.verification_mode: none"

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
  username: "elastic"
  password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ssl.certificate_authorities: "/etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt"
  index: "myindex"
  pipeline: "mypipeline"
```